# SQL Replace duplicate result with 0, based on other columns

Tags: oracle, plsql

The goal is to return the same result,but  i to substitute "value" with null
when  row_id not in   max for product.

```
 current result:
            row_id   product    value  product_id

               101  product1    10      1
               102  product1    10      1
               103  product1    10      1
               104  product2    20      2
               105  product3    20      2
               106  product3    30      3
               107  product3    30      3
               108  product4    40      4



       CREATE TABLE tbl26 (row_id int, product VARCHAR2(30), value int, product_id int);

       insert into tbl26 (row_id,product,value, product_id)
       SELECT 101,  'product1', 10, 1    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
       SELECT 102,  'product1', 10, 1    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
       SELECT 103,  'product1', 10, 1   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
       SELECT 104,  'product2', 20, 2   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
       SELECT 105,  'product3', 20, 2   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
       SELECT 106,  'product3', 30, 3   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
       SELECT 107,  'product3', 30, 3   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
       SELECT 108,  'product4', 40, 4   FROM DUAL;
```

I tried with PARTITION BY,but I didn't get the desired result.
Expected result:

```
             row_id   product    value  product_id

              101   product1    0       1
              102   product1    0       1
              103   product1    10      1
              104   product2    0       2
              105   product3    20      2
              106   product3    0       3
              107   product3    30      3
              108   product4    40      4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT row_id
      ,product
      ,CASE
           WHEN MAX(row_id)
                OVER(PARTITION BY product_id) = row_id THEN
              value
           ELSE
              0
        END as value
      ,product_id
  FROM tbl26;


    ROW_ID PRODUCT                             VALUE PRODUCT_ID
---------- ------------------------------ ---------- ----------
       101 product1                                0          1
       102 product1                                0          1
       103 product1                               10          1
       104 product2                                0          2
       105 product3                               20          2
       106 product3                                0          3
       107 product3                               30          3
       108 product4                               40          4
```

Answer (score 0):

Use window function `ROW_NUMBER` to find the latest record and use column value against it using `CASE..WHEN` as follows:

```
SELECT row_id,product,
       CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() 
                   OVER (PARTITION BY product_id ORDER BY row_id DESC) = 1 
            THEN value 
       END AS VALUE, 
       product_id
FROM tbl26;
```